# Grouped and reversed bar plot in base R when the length of variables are not equal

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar plot in base R, so not with ggplot, that is grouped and reversed, and I found a lot of similar questions and answers but it seems none of them works for me.
My database is about Eurovision song contest 2007, this is the link towards it: https://www.kaggle.com/datagraver/eurovision-song-contest-scores-19752019

and this is the code for cleaning and getting the database I'm working with:

```
cela_baza <- read.csv("eurovision_song_contest_1975_2019.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

evro2007_pocetna<-cela_baza[cela_baza$Year=='2007',]

evro2007_aggr<-aggregate(evro2007_pocetna$Points~evro2007_pocetna$From.country+
                         evro2007_pocetna$To.country,FUN=mean)

colnames(evro2007_aggr) <- c('From country', 'To country','Points')

evro2007<-evro2007_aggr[!(evro2007_aggr$`From country`==evro2007_aggr$`To country`),]

nrow(subset(evro2007, evro2007$Points== 0 ))

evro2007_zero<- subset(evro2007, evro2007$Points> 0 )
```

What I need is a bar plot with number of points on x-axis and countries that participated in competition on y-axis, each country has three grouped bars of different color: first represents how many points that country gave to Serbia (winner), second points to Ukraine (2nd place) and third points to Russia (3rd place). So it is grouped and reversed, and I found code for that, but my problem is that not all of the participating countries gave points to these three countries I need so always occurs some errors.

Code for ggplot will work too, I can't install it on my old PC, but I will ask someone to do it for me, as long as I have the code, thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do what you're describing, but the resulting plot is horrible because of the number of countries on the x axis (42, with three bars each), and the limitations of base R's `barplot`.

Here's how we can get the data in the correct format:

```r
winners <- evro2007[evro2007$`To country` == "Ukraine" | 
           evro2007$`To country` == "Russia" | 
           evro2007$`To country` == "Serbia",]
self <- data.frame(`From country` = c("Serbia", "Ukraine", "Russia"),
                   `To country` = c("Serbia", "Ukraine", "Russia"),
                   Points = c(0, 0, 0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(self) <- names(winners)
winners <- rbind(winners, self)
winners <- winners[order(winners$`From country`, winners$`To country`),]
```

However, the base R barplot looks like this:

```
barplot(Points ~ `To country` + `From country`, 
        data = winners, beside = TRUE, cex.names = 0.3)
```

[image]

The countries are illegible, and the plot difficult to interpret.

Whereas, using `ggplot`:

```
winners$`To country` <- factor(winners$`To country`, 
                               levels = c("Serbia", "Ukraine", "Russia"))

ggplot(winners, aes(`To country`, Points, fill = `To country`)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(.~`From country`) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: Woow, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks! I've tried to do similar thing with one country getting points from jury/public, but this error appears:                                                     
   Error in names(self) <- names(smakedonija) : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [3]

Comment: Where am I wrong, here's my code:                                                               
 smakedonija <- cela_baza [cela_baza$Year=='2019'& cela_baza$Jury.or.Televoting=='J'&cela_baza$To.country=='North Macedonia'| 
                            cela_baza$Year=='2019'& cela_baza$Jury.or.Televoting=='T'&cela_baza$To.country=='North Macedonia',]
self <- data.frame(`Jury.or.Televoting` = c("J","T"),
                   `To country` = c("North Macedonia", "North Macedonia"),
                   Points = c(0, 0),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: names(self) <- names(smakedonija)
smakedonija <- rbind(smakedonija, self)
smakedonija <- smakedonija[order(smakedonija$`Jury.or.Televoting`, smakedonija$`To country`),]

Comment: I hope you can follow my (actually your:) code as it's pretty bad edited here:D @Allan Cameron

Comment: I would appreciate anyone's help too, if anyone find what's mistake in my code in comments just let me now

Comment: @user13646116 the fields you have in `self` don't match the fields you have in `smakedonija`. You probably don't need to add the `self` data frame here.

Comment: I did it with creating smakedonija2 that has only data I need from smakedonija, thank you  sooo much, you helped me a great deal;)